# Where do I define custom glyphs?

Tags: symbols, anki

I want to just add a few symbols, but am having a very hard time finding out where to do it. Specifically, I am wanting to integrate these commands:

```
\def\angle#1{\leavevmode\hbox{\vtop{\vbox{\hrule\kern1pt
        \hbox{{$\scriptstyle #1$}\kern1pt}}
      \kern1pt}\vrule}\kern1pt}

\def\tcelife#1{{\buildrel \circ \over e}_{#1}}
```

to invoke

```
\tcelife{x:\angle n}
```

However, I cannot find where to actually put this code. I have `MiKTeX 2.9` installed, using Windows.

Edit: I am using Anki, do not deal directly with tex - I only use the syntax to build flash cards, so I am pretty ignorant of the back end.

Thanks

Comment: if this is for just one document, you can put it in the preamble for that file.  then it will be easy to find later.

Comment: I use Anki to create electronic flash cards, so I am really not familiar with the libraries of tex at all. In the program I just use latex markup to publish a flash card - that is a long way of saying I don't know where the preamble is, or if that is applicable to what I'm trying to do. Thank you for the response